# awk to capture repeating groups of lines between two patterns

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file like:

```sh
$ cat test.txt
one
two
--------------
three
four
--------------
five
six
--------------
seven
eight
--------------
nine
ten
```

I am trying to use `awk` to capture the text between the two lines of `--------------`.

Output I am trying for:

```sh
$ cat test.txt
three
four

seven
eight
```

Here is what I have so far

```sh
awk '/^--------------$/{flag=1;next}/^--------------$/{flag=0}flag' test.txt
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '{x=sub(/^-+$/,"")} f; x{f=!f}' file
three
four

seven
eight
```

The sub() replaces all `---` lines with blanks and saves the fact it did that in `x` to remember that the current line was a `---` line. The `x(f=!f}` toggles `f` between 0 and 1 for every `---` line. The `f;` prints the current line when `f` is true since `{print}` is the default action given a true condition.

Comment: This seems the best option.. I can now separate the different groups with `awk '{x=sub(/^-+$/,"---")} f; x{f=!f}' test.txt`

Comment: Can you unpack what is going on this awk script?

Comment: Sure, I just added an explanation. You can always add `print` statements to every action block to dump the variables to see when/how they're being set if you like.

Comment: Thank you for this.. if I can ask one more thing: if I run this on multiple files, can I print the file name for just the matches? I updated my question to show what I  have tried... happy to make it a new question if you want. :D

Comment: New question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55525724/printing-name-of-files-that-match-awk-script

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v RS='\n-+' '!(NR%2)' file

three
four

seven
eight
```

needs multi-char RS support (gawk).  It defines the record separator, therefore records between the separators.  Here we ask to print the even records.

Or,

```
$ awk '/^-+$/{f=!f; if(f) print ""; next} f' file

three
four

seven
eight
```

this is similar to your solution, flip the flag at every occurrence of the pattern and print when flag is set.  Add an empty line before to separate groups.

Comment: I will test that when I get back to my machine. Would you mind explaining what is going on in those commands?

Comment: Trying to ensure I only use lines that are all dashes: `awk -v RS='\n-+\n' '!(NR%2)' test.txt`, which removes blank lines from the output.. Is there a way I can now use something to separate the records in the output?

Comment: set ORS to double newline.

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat like this :

```
sed 's/^-\{14\}//' file
```

Comment: I want the lines *between* the patterns.. and I cannot modify the files.. (of course I can just remove `-i` to stop that).