# Printing name of files that match awk script

Tags: bash, awk

Following on from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55504589/awk-to-capture-repeating-groups-of-lines-between-two-patterns)

I have multiple text files that may or may not have repeating groups of text surrounded by dashed lines. All the lorem ipsum text should not be included in the output.

```sh
$ cat /tmp/testAwk/file1.txt


--------------
important text one
important text two
--------------

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
consectetur adipiscing elit

--------------
important text three
important text four
--------------

sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua

Ut enim ad minim veniam
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
ex ea commodo consequat


$ cat /tmp/testAwk/file2.txt
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit

--------------
important text one
important text two
--------------

in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
eu fugiat nulla pariatur

non proident, sunt

--------------
important text three
important text four
--------------

Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat

$ cat /tmp/testAwk/file3.txt
consequuntur magni dolores
sed quia non numquam

Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit
```

I am trying to use `awk` to capture the text between the two lines of `--------------` and print out the names of files that match the pattern.

I took the fantastic reply from @Ed Morton to my previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55507707/257233

```
awk '{x=sub(/^-+$/,"")} f; x{f=!f}' *.txt
```

I tried to adapt it to print out the file names of those files that match the pattern and indent the results. I couldn't work out how to do the whole job in `awk`, so I ended up with some `grep` and `sed` in there as well.

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{print FILENAME} {x=sub(/^-+$/,"---")} f; x{f=!f}' $(grep -E '^-+$' /tmp/testAwk/*.txt -l) | sed -re 's/^([^\/])/   \1/'
/tmp/testAwk/file1.txt
   important text one
   important text two
   ---
   important text three
   important text four
   ---
/tmp/testAwk/file2.txt
   important text one
   important text two
   ---
   important text three
   important text four
   ---
```

Can I do the above just with awk?

Comment: Updated the question to add what output I am looking for.

Comment: Updated the question to provide a more accurate test situation, to properly show what I have so far and what the output looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it, especially since your use case seems to be evolving to require more functionality so cramming it into a brief one-liner isn't the best approach:

```
$ cat tst.awk
FNR==1 { delimCnt=inBlock=block="" }
/^-+$/ {
    inBlock = (++delimCnt % 2)
    if ( !inBlock ) {
        if (delimCnt > 1) {
            if (delimCnt == 2) {
                print FILENAME
            }
            print block "   ---"
        }
        block = ""
    }
    next
}
inBlock { block = block "   " $0 ORS }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
file1.txt
   important text one
   important text two
   ---
   important text three
   important text four
   ---
file2.txt
   important text one
   important text two
   ---
   important text three
   important text four
   ---
```

Comment: That's it! It works perfectly against my updated example and you wrote that before I finished updating my question.. I would double upvote.. Need to study this and try and understand better how to script with Awk.